# Сломанные биндинги

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пишу проект на архитектуре MVVM. В интерфейсе есть биндинги. Сами биндинги работают, но очень странно. К примеру я беру кол-во элементов в ProxyProvider.Pool. (это list, и он пустой).Выводит 0. Добавляю в конструктор VM ProxyProvider.Pool.Add(new Proxy()); уже показывает 1.

А теперь внимание: делаю ProxyProvider.Pool.Add(new Proxy()); но уже в команде. Нажимаю кнопку, все выполняется(проверял дебаггером), кол-во элементов увеличилось, но биндинг не сработал.

Вопрос: где тут может быть ошибка? Строку  ProxyProvider.Pool.Add(new Proxy()); прямо копировал вставлял, везде реализован INPC, класс ViewModel раскидан по разным файлам (partial), студию перезапускал.

Comment: `Вопрос: где тут может быть ошибка?` - `это list`. У `List<>` нет реализации интерфейса `INotifyCollectionChanged`, он есть у `ObservableCollection<>` и `BindingList<>`.

Comment: Знал что есть такая штука как ObservableCollection, но думал что реализации INPC достаточно.В итоге промучился несколько часов. Большое спасибо, я уж думал что сойду с ума.

Comment: INPC создан исключительно для оповещения об изменении свойств (например если вы делаете `ProxyProvider.Pool = new List<Proxy>()`). Если надо оповестить об изменении элементов **коллекции** (добавление/удаление), то используется INCC.